# How can I see the messages exchanged between akka actors in a cluster through tcpdump

Tags: tcp, akka, cluster-computing, tcpdump, akka-cluster

I have an akka-cluster project:

https://github.com/roclas/akka-distributed-hash

Which is basically a distributed HashMap across the nodes of a cluster.

I want to be able to read (using tcpdump or wireshark or something similar) the messages exchanged between actors in different virtual machines.

How could I do it?

Doing a TCP dump, I only see the "cluster messages" but not the messages exchanged by different actors in different virtual machines.

If I start a node on port 2551: sbt "run 2551" (will be the master)

and another node on port 2552: sbt "run 2552"

What is actually happening when I do this?:

curl -X PUT http://localhost:8551 --data "hello=333&world=456"

I understand that:

1. the master node's web service receives the http put request
2. the master node changes its HashMap and sends a message to the second node's actor so that it updates its hash (<-this is the part that I want to trace)
3. the second node updates its hash (so it means that the message has been succesfuly received). How haven't I been able to see that message using TCP dump? (I see nothing has been received on port 2552, and I've also done a tcpdump listening to all network interfaces and all ports, and from the moment I send the http put message to the moment when the hash is updated in the second node, no tcp message seem to contain the akka message that the actor in the master node sends to the actor on the second node)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/akka-user/tcpdump/akka-user/pipFVxI6XsU/XlLh0e_8v_0J

The messages I was looking for were sent over port 2552 and 2551, just didn't find them among all the messages cluster nodes send to each other, but filtering by segment size I was able to isolate the ones I wanted and take a look and how they look like internally.